# Hot swapping of Jars in production

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, hotswap, dcevm

I have a production fleet of a bunch of servers. I would like to know the viability of using technologies JRebel, or DCEVM + Hotswap agent, or OSGi framework based bundle reload for hotswapping jars in production. As far as I understand, JRebel is quite feature rich in its offering but I don't know if using it in production is safe. Their license seems to count developers working which also indicates that the intent is to cater to developers and not production systems.

Answer (score 3):

JRebel, DCEVM + Hotswap agent or other reloading technologies are development tools and therefore meant to be used only in development environment.

While reloading in production may work, it's not recommended using JRebel in a production environment. Additionally, JRebel does come with some performance and memory overhead which is certainly not desirable in production.

Answer (score 1):

The only viable technology for doing this in production is OSGi. This requirement has been core to the design of OSGi since the late 1990s.

JRebel is a development tool, not intended for production usage, and DCEVM is an academic research project.